# How to Asp Net Bootstrap Show database entries?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <table  name="GridView" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Haber Adı</th>
        <th>Link</th>
        <th>Yayınlanma Sati</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
   <input type="password" class="form-control"  id="sifre" runat="server" />
        <td id="t_haberadı" runat="server">  </td>
        <td id="t_link" runat="server">2</td>
        <td id="t_saat" runat="server">3</td>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</html>
```

//code behind

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(veriler, bag);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

//da.Fill(ds);
//GridView1.DataSource = ds;
//GridView1.DataBind();
```

**Bootstrap table  members will show database please help me
How can I show my data?,
Show me the data I want to do Bootstrap table

//Bir ya da birden fazla satırların sonuç olarak döneceği sorgularda SqlCommand' ın ExecuteReader özelliği kullanılmaktadır. ExecuteReader geriye SqlDataReader tipinde veri döndürmektedir.//
**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 ">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table name="GridView" class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Haber Adı</th>
                            <th>Link</th>
                            <th>Yayınlanma Sati</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="sifre" runat="server" />
                            <td id="t_haberadı" runat="server">  </td>
                            <td id="t_link" runat="server">2</td>
                            <td id="t_saat" runat="server">3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hi best way to show a responsive table will be to use bootstrap.

I would recommend you do something like

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/47548d/responsive-grid-view-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: link only answer is not recommended, link get remove or change into 404